# What is the single word for the way money throwing on stripper?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the single word for money throwing on stripper?

We just don't throw money like that, we just **slide** each note money on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people use ***making it rain*** to describe this action, though this phrase has multiple senses.

The more common sense is given by [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=make%20it%20rain&page=2) as:

> When you have a wad of cash and throw it in the air in a strip club.

But people also use it to refer to the specific action you describe, as evinced in this [video](https://m.youtube.com/?#/watch?v=-rIWJuFzr0o) which shows Rhianna doing it (see second 15).